# Adding a new column in a recordset

Tags: excel, database, vba, recordset

I'm a creating a vba macro for an Excel database. The database is about a number of people and the time spent by them on each of their projects. Whenever there's a new user, a new column adds up. 
So, I tried with rs.Fields.Append but it's not working. :( can you help me?

```
Sub AjoutEnregistrement()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim Project As String
Dim MyCheck As Boolean
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim i As Variant
MyFile = "D:\Users\X\Documents\Checkin__2018.xlsm"
LoginID = "A01825112"
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
Fichier & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=No'"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "SELECT * from [AUGUST$] ", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
rs.Fields.Append "LoginID"
rs.AddNew

rs.Update
rs.Close
cnn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: So, you're just trying to add a new header to a spreadsheet? Why use ADODB for that?

Comment: No, I'm also constantly updating the time. Actually, I've 2 excel files. The first one has an userform in which users pick the project they're going to work on and start the timer. Once, they're done, they stop the timer and the time is sent to my database Excel file.
The biggest problem I'm facing is I can't able to add columns. 
I'm new to macro and database so this is the "easiest" way I found online.

Comment: HOW is it "not working"? Are you getting an error message? What is it?

Answer (score -1):

Excel isn't a database, and you're not meant to interact with it this way. ADODB recordsets let you read/write recordsets to/from Excel, but they're not meant to be updated by VBA; as far as I know, what you're trying to do here isn't possible. It really sounds like Access would serve your needs far better than Excel would.

If you must use Excel, you should just do what you're trying to do directly. That is, add a column to a spreadsheet.

You can use the following sub to do so, given a worksheet and the header of the new column

```
Sub addHeader(ws As Worksheet, newColHeader As String)
    Dim lastCol As Long

    lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column
    ws.Cells(1, lastCol + 1).Value = newColHeader
End Sub
```

In your example, you would call it with

```
addHeader Workbooks("Checkin__2018.xlsm").Worksheets("AUGUST$"), LoginID
```

Comment: Thank you. But it's still not working  :/ At the line, `addHeader Workbooks("Checkin__2018.xlsm").Worksheets("AUGUST$"), LoginID`
I'm getting the following error `Run Time error 9 : Subscript out of range` though the file and the sheet exist

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add a column to an ADODB RecordSet after the RecordSet has been opened. Josh's answer is good - add the column in Excel and re-query.

Comment: Hey MiS, this type of contribution should instead be left as a comment to either the question or Josh's answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer